# How can I do manual Caching in NextJS

Tags: caching, next.js, next.js13

I want to do manual caching in NextJS. Let say I want to store my name in cache and then display it, by fetching it from cache in my NextJS webapp.

I have tried library like 'lru-cache' and 'memory-cache' but they are not storing my data in cache. I even looked in application tab of inspect, but nothing was store there.